# Are stringstream read failures non-deterministic?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some code that behaves differently on different compiler's:

```
std::string strVal = "11";
std::stringstream stream( strVal );  
auto value = false;

if( !( stream >> std::noboolalpha >> value ) )
{
    // report error - this path is taken on both compilers
}

// "value" is "false" here on in VS 2017, but "true" on GCC 4.6
```

Is the difference in behavior expected, or is it a bug in GCC?

According to [cppprefence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.

However, `value` is being modified to `true` on GCC 4.6.

Comment: FYI: the part you quoted is until C++11.  In C++11 and beyond *If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is written and failbit flag is set.*

Comment: @NathanOliver However compiling with `-std=c++03` on GCC still results in `true` which shouldn't happen.

Comment: try `-std=c++11` on gcc

Comment: @SombreroChicken - It should happen actually. :-)  As the wording is the result of [a defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3246.html#23) on the original standard it can be applied retroactively as a bug fix. (Just took 12 years to resolve, Complicated stuff this! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC bug. [facet.num.get.virtuals]/6:

> *Effects:* If `(str.flags()&ios_­base​::​boolalpha) == 0` then input
>   proceeds as it would for a `long` except that if a value is being stored
>   into `val`, the value is determined according to the following: If the
>   value to be stored is `0` then `false` is stored. If the value is `1` then
>   `true` is stored. Otherwise `true` is stored and `ios_­base​::​failbit` is
>   assigned to `err`.

Comment: That is correct for C++11, but earlier versions had this as the last sentence: "Otherwise err |=ios_base::failbit is performed and no value is stored."

Comment: @metal 1) that's a defect in the standard, so the bug was in the standard plus MSVC. Besides, 2) MSVC never claims to support C++03 anyway. Its minimum `/std` is C++14.

Answer (score 1):

[Running with VC 19 (aka VS2015)](http://rextester.com/JDZD80577), your sample code shows `value` is `false`.

On [GCC 8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5SHyVkgvF2yakZJM) back to 4.4.7 with whatever `-std=` flag, it always showed that `value` was changed to true.

[In C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf), it is supposed to set the value to true, but in [previous standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) it was supposed to leave it unchanged, which T.C. notes was a defect in the standard itself. Thus MSVC is non-conformant in C++11 and GCC was non-conformant under earlier standards but is conformant now.

Comment: Does @NathanOliver's comment "If extraction results in the value too large .. std::numeric_limits<T>::max()" suggest that GCC is now behaving correctly (whereas it wasn't before c++11) and now VC is now non-conforming?